# Elastic-search index not show in kibana using Jhipster

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, jhipster

Project : Jhipster - Document Management

Docker Configuration : MySQL, Elasticsearch, Kibana

Issue : Elasticsearch index work in project but their data not shown in kibana

Question : I want to open my data in kibana using querystring.

- When i perform any file upload related function entry place and i also get using JPA querystring search method.
- I want to see my data which i stored in elasticsearch using kibana.
- I created some demo project of elk but in jhipster i'm bit confused how to handle
- Someone have idea how to do samething in jhipster is there anything to enable in it.
- Also i want to know how jhipster deal with logstash with their predefine configuration.

Code :

Elasticsearch.yml

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  docy-elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.8.6
    container_name: docy-elasticsearch
    volumes:
       - ~/volumes/jhipster/docy/elasticsearch/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    restart: always
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATA_JEST_URI=http://docy-elasticsearch:9200/
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=true
      - xpack.ml.enabled=true
      - xpack.graph.enabled=true
      - xpack.watcher.enabled=true
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=false
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
      - discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    networks:
      elk:
        aliases:
          - docy-elasticsearch
networks:
  elk:
```

Kibana.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  docy-kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.8.6
    container_name: docy-kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://docy-elasticsearch:9200/
      - xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled=true
    networks:
      - elk
networks:
  elk:
```

Answer (score 0):

I setup volumes in elastic-search yml

```
- ../../../../doc/ELK_Data/data/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/
```

Through this it create index on project startup and showing index.
And when i set following parameter true it show my indexes but data which i stored before do this are place in my actual index(document) but after doing this data store in some .monitoring-es-. I'm confused with behavior. Can some one guide me. I want to store it in document and perform action through kibana.

```
- xpack.monitoring.enabled=true
- xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled=true
```